# Bluetooth Android issue

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am running a multi thread application on android and adobe air, in native android 2 bluetooth sockets are set up and a couple of server threads for the air app to communicate with the bluetooth sockets of native android. It's basically socket programming and it all works on one device I used to programme it.

The device i used to develop this app was slow, i therefore got myself another tablet to test (android vega) and it is very fast at communicating my bluetooth data as it has 2.1edr version.

The problem is with the Advent Vega tablet the bluetooth streams just disconnect for no apparent reason intermittently and in the adb log window i just get trying to connect to device all of a sudden when the disconnect occurs, i have no mention of the crash anywhere in the log, this happens to both bluetooth connected threads at the same time so it must be something to do with the bluetooth radio im suspecting. The other tablet device runs the app fine but slower (no disconnects). I have even installed a custom 3.0 rom on the vega to see if it was a os problem but the disconnect problem persisted on 3.0 as well.

Due to the fact there is no mention of this in the adb log i am just basically staring at a screen with no idea of why it disconnects for 2 days now!! The only way to get the app to run again after this disconnection occurs is to restart the bluetooth on the device but this disconnect occurs again eventually when next run. It seems to improve the amount of time it stays alive tansferring data when the app is first run afater a re boot.

I have gone through all code of the run() and stopping() of each thread and it seems to exit gracefully, i close the bluetooth sockets only, it seems from research no need to close the bluetooth input and output but i have also tried that approach to closing.

Can anyone offer suggestions as to why both bluetooth read/write loops would just stop all of a sudden and disconnect? Seemingly effecting the adb log as well as it just says trying to connect...

Or any suggestions as to how to better debug when this occurs?

Or even what somebody else would do in this situation.

Hope someone can help, i have a great phone remote app for the android tablet owner community and it hinges on this final issue which i have been stuck on for 2 days.

Comment: You really should show your code. Bluetooth and Android can be quite surprising. I experienced some devices that weren't able to connect after some time anymore. The reasons were mostly known bugs for this these exact devices. After a power cycle (not only deactivate/reactivate bluetooth or even reboot) I could work with bluetooth again.  See this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41415 Also note there is this nasty "use reflection to connect via RFCOMM" advice out there in the world. Don't do that. It bypasses the SDP-Service-Lookup and always uses a fixed channel.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with disconnects, and implemented a keepalive by sending a ping request and a ping ack.
This worked fine for me...

Comment: Hi Erik, can you please post some code on how to send and ack ping using bluetooth?